# vb.net - draw rectangle filled with white noise on a image

Tags: vb.net, draw, rectangles, whitenoise

I use following code to draw a rectangle on a image:

```
 Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(augImage)
 Dim rect As New Rectangle(xposLabel, yposLabel, w, h)
 gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rect)
```

now, I would need this rectangle to be filled with white noise. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you need actual *white noise* (normal distribution, mean is zero), or just what *looks like* a white noise representation? If the latter, use a Bitmap as the source of a TextureBrush and fill the area with that. Otherwise, build a Bitmap with `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`, the use the Random class to generate `0` and `1` values, use `Bitmap.LockBits()` to get the `BitmapData`, use a `Byte()` buffer to store the random values (`dim value = CByte((rnd.Next(2) * 255)`), copy the buffer over the `BitmapData` and you have a white noise image you can draw over another.

Comment: @Jimi something that looks like white noise is ok. but it must be random. So i guess i have to use your second sugestion. isnt it quite slow to draw a random noise each time? I have to do it for about 50.000 times in a loop.

Comment: It depends on the size of white noise image. For example, a 1000x1000 image should take 10~12ms to generate, which - in your context - is quite a lot.  So, you could generate the bitmaps in a parallel Task, use a `ConcurrentQueue<Image>` to dequeue the random image in the drawing procedure. Or, generate a single, quite large white noise image, then use the TextureBrush ctor overload that allows to specify a Rectangle, to get a *random piece* of the large image and use that *random piece* as the source Bitmap of the TextureBrush (I hope what I said is clear enough :)